# Android Gradle Plugin Error. Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

This is the exact error I'm getting while making a build in release Variant.

```
Error:(57, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
```

Possible causes:

The project 'spot' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Fix plugin version and sync project

The project 'spot' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file